# How to access elements of a Matrix using loops

Tags: c, loops, matrix

I have two 4x4 multidimensional arrays, and the rows and columns are marked as being `A`, `B`, `C` and `D`. When the user inputs the co-ordinates, the value of known_location_info selected is changed to the value of bomb_location_info. So for example, if `AA` was input then the value of `[1][1]` on `known_location_info` is changed to the value of `[1][1]` on `bomb_location_info`. At the moment I am only getting the first element to change regardless of what co-ordinates are entered. What is incorrect in my loop?

```c
char inputRow;
char inputColumn;
char letterA = 'A';

void display(int known_location_info[][DIM], int size) {

    printf("  A  B  C  D\n");

    for (int row = 0; row < DIM; row++) {

        printf("%c", letterA);
        letterA++;

        for (int column = 0; column < DIM; column++) {
            printf("%d ", known_location_info[row][column]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("Please select a row and column: ");
    scanf("%c, %c", &inputRow, &inputColumn);
}

void update_known_info(int row, int col, int bomb_location_info[][DIM], 
                       int known_location_info[][DIM]) {

    for (inputRow = letterA; inputRow < DIM; inputRow++) {
        for (inputColumn = letterA; inputColumn < DIM; inputColumn++) {
            row++;
            col++;
        }
    }

    known_location_info[row][col] = bomb_location_info[row][col];
}
```

Comment: Have you checked the values of `inputRow` and `inputColumn`?

Answer (score 0):

Access matrix using chars that scanned from the user is not a good idea. because every char is represented by an ASCII code. hence you will have an implicit offset of the ascii value of the letter (for example ASCII fo A = 64. in the other hand matrixes are like arrays. they are indexed starting from 0. you may retrieve the ascii offset before starting your loops..

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <assert.h>

#define DIM 4

void display(int known_location_info[][DIM]) {

    printf("  A  B  C  D\n");

    for (int row = 0; row < DIM; ++row) {
        printf("%c ", 'A' + row);
        for (int column = 0; column < DIM; ++column)
            printf("%2d ", known_location_info[row][column]);
        putchar('\n');
    }

    printf("Please select a row and column: ");
    char inputRow; char inputColumn;
    if (scanf(" %c, %c", &inputRow, &inputColumn) != 2 ||
        inputRow < 'A' || 'A' + DIM < inputRow ||
        inputColumn < 'A' || 'A' + DIM < inputRow)
    {
        // handle input error
    }
}

void update_known_info(char row, char col, int bomb_location_info[][DIM],
                       int known_location_info[][DIM])
{
    row -= 'A';
    col -= 'A';

    assert(0 <= row && row < DIM && 0 <= col && col < DIM);

    known_location_info[row][col] = bomb_location_info[row][col];
}
```